# TFS 2010 Runscript

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

How can I run a batch file or script from my TFS 2010 build definition?

I've used the RunScript activity from my build definition, and I've tried to add the right assemblies. I get this message back:

> TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build
>   definition \DataVerify\KlocworkBuild: Cannot create unknown type
>   '{clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities}RunScript'.

Maybe it's a problem with the assemblies? There's a Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.dll
assembly, but it looks like version 12, and there is no version 10.

If I can get the right assemblies that would be helpful. Or if there's another way to run a batch file or script, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Invoke-Process activity yet? A lot of modifications to build process templates use it combined with cmd.exe passing build details to accomplish the tasks.